# Getting children of a node after fxml load

Tags: java, javafx

I have this problem with the scrollPane where content is blurry I managed to fix it like this:

```
        Node scrollPaneSkin = menuScroll.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0);
        scrollPaneSkin.setCache(false);
```

I am taking the first child of the scrollPane which is a scrollPaneSkin and setting it's cache to false, but when I do It in initialize() the node is still not rendered or something, because I am getting NullPointerException. So I am doing it with a timeline:

```
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(15),event -> {
        Node scrollPaneSkin = menuScroll.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0);
        scrollPaneSkin.setCache(false);
    }));
    timeline.play();
```

And it is working, but I feel that there is a better way to do it. Same is happening if I try to get the scene of a node from the fxml in the initialize(). How can I get the children right away in the initialize() method?

Comment: The `Skin` is not part of a `Control`'s children list; you're getting some `Node` that's probably added by the `Skin`, but not the `Skin` itself. Have you tried setting the `cache` property on the `ScrollPane` itself?

Comment: @Slaw I tried many things the the only thing that fixed it was an answer that extends the all ScrollPane and creates a new one with a new extended ScrollPaneSkin that the cache is set to false https://stackoverflow.com/a/26213480/10696487.  But then I managed to do it like this. I am getting a Skin because when I try to take the children and cast it to let's say VBox I am getting "ClassCastException: class javafx.scene.control.skin.ScrollPaneSkin$5 cannot be cast to class javafx.scene.layout.VBox" so I just take it as Node and it is working.

Comment: @Slaw or maybe ScrollPaneSkin$5 is not a skin maybe it's the viewRect of the scrollPaneSkin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this through listeners, rather than trying to wait a certain amount of time. What you listen to is up to you. One option is to listen to the `skin` property of the `ScrollPane`.

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML private ScrollPane sp;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // may want to remove the listener once it does its job
        sp.skinProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
            if (nv != null) {
                sp.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0).setCache(false);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Another option is to listen to the children of the `ScrollPane` and react when the appropriate node is added. Looking at the source code the node is an anonymous subclass of `StackPane` whose style class is `"viewport"`.

Note that this code is dependent on both `ScrollPane` using `ScrollPaneSkin` as it's skin and the internal implementation of `ScrollPaneSkin`. Be careful if you change the skin, which can be done via code, FXML, or CSS. And be careful when changing JavaFX versions; I tried the above example using Java 8u202 though it doesn't look like anything relevant changed by JavaFX 11.0.2.